# Duplicates varying slightly in string values with additional temporal aspect

Tags: twitter, duplicates, postgresql-9.2, similarity

I use emergency tweets from the netherlands for a project. There are sometimes more than one tweet regarding one event, varying slightly in timestamp and in the string of the tweet itself. I want to delete those "duplicates".

So, In my database if have rows which are quite alike but not exactly the same like

```
    "2014-01-11 10:01:17";"HV 1 METINGEN (+Inc,net: 1+) (KLEIN OGS) (slachtoffers: ) , Van Ostadestraat 332 AMSTERDAM [ ]  "
    "2014-01-11 09:59:06";"HV 1 METINGEN (+Inc,net: 1+) (KLEIN OGS) (slachtoffers:1) , Van Ostadestraat 332 AMSTERDAM ]  "
```

The Problem is that i have to take into account the temporal aspect and can't just rely on the string. The text can occur multiple times.

Ideal would be an approach where i delete all rows within a temporal buffer of 10 minutes after the first tweet, when the text similarity is over a threshold of 0.75.

for the string comparison i tried similarity(text,text) see
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgtrgm.html

for the time aggregation i used :
(extract(minute FROM timestamp_column)::int / 10)
in addition to the regular YYYY-MM-DD-HH24 time aggregation

Any help is appreciated.